# Selected Menu effect

Tags: html, css

I managed to create a hover effect on my menu.

I want that when the user selects a menu it remains orange.

How do I create such effect on my menu?

I am using custom menu icon with a wordpress plugin

This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
    .menu-item a img {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
}
#menu-meniu >li {padding-left:80px;}
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered img.hovered-image,
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered:hover img.menu-image {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered:hover img.hovered-image {
    opacity: 1;
}
.menu-item a.menu-image-title-after.menu-image-not-hovered img,
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered.menu-image-title-after .menu-image-hover-wrapper {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.menu-item a.menu-image-title-before.menu-image-not-hovered img,
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered.menu-image-title-before .menu-image-hover-wrapper {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the post, and read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: see that the top menu works so, it would be a solution to discover its functionality

Comment: @Mihai andrei provide your HTML code

Comment: This is the code for my menu .... I want to create an effect ACTIVE

Answer (score 1):

Use your hover code and target the `current-menu-item` class.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. You just need to add the class .current-menu-item to your CSS. This is the default "active" for menus in WordPress.